# improving join performance on sql server table

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2016

I have a table on sql server lets say TableA.
and a another table as TableB.Both of these tables are heavily loaded.

Table A is loaded with records 35883788. It is holding a lot of duplicates on column program_id.

Table B is loaded with records 27343331. It is also holding a duplicate on column on program_id.
For some business reason we need to keep duplicate records on program_id on both the tables.

Now I am performing a left join on given table as:

```
select 
a.*,b.date_of_birth,
datediff(year,b.date_of_birth,a.from_date)-
(case when dateadd(year,
           datediff(year,b.date_of_birth,a.from_date),b.date_of_birth)
           > a.from_date then 1 else 0
                   end) as age_final,
case when datediff(yyyy,b.date_of_birth,a.from_date) is null then ''
     when datediff(yyyy,b.date_of_birth,a.from_date) <=1 then 'less than 1 year'
     when datediff(yyyy,b.date_of_birth,a.from_date) <=17 then 'then 1 - 17 year'
     when datediff(yyyy,b.date_of_birth,a.from_date) <=29 then 'then 19 - 29 year'
     when datediff(yyyy,b.date_of_birth,a.from_date) <=39 then 'then 30 - 39 year'
     when datediff(yyyy,b.date_of_birth,a.from_date) <=49 then 'then 40 - 49 year'
     when datediff(yyyy,b.date_of_birth,a.from_date) <=59 then 'then 50 - 59 year'
     when datediff(yyyy,b.date_of_birth,a.from_date) <=64 then 'then 60 - 64 year'
else 'More than 64 years' end as Age_band
from TableA a 
left join ( select program_id,date_of_birth,max(process_date) 
            from TableB 
            group by program_id,date_of_birth) b
    on a.program_id=b.program_id;
```

my inner query is giving me a unique set of program_id as using group by statement.

None of these tables are indexed. If I have to create an index on both the tables, what kind of index do I need to have on program_id for both the tables.

what all other things I can take care of to improve the joining performance.

need suggestion to optimize the join and indexes.

Comment: `TableB (program_id, date_of_birth, process_date)` and `TableA (program_id)`.

Comment: both the tables have duplicates for column program_id, what kind of index do you suggest for both the tables

Comment: Everything is said already, I can add nothing.

Comment: Do you need the `max(process_date)` to force the unique set of `program_id`'s in the inner query or does it not matter (can it be random record or does it need the last processed date?) The indexes are nonclustered rowstore indexes, you should read up on indexes before implementing them.

Comment: @ Randi Vertongen. yeah I am forcing it to have a unique set of program_id.s. This table is having multiple process_date for each set of duplicate values on column program_id and DOB. so I have to select a max(process_date) and using group by it's giving me a unque set of record for each program_id.

Comment: Alright that is understandable, but does it have to be the record based on `max(process_date)`? Could it also theoretically be `MIN((process_date)`?

Comment: It should be max(process_date) as per the business requirement we are following.

Comment: Is it fine to create nonclustered index (program_id, date_of_birth, process_date) for tableB and nonclustered index (program_id) for tableA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*DDL & DML at the bottom*

**Standard indexes that could be created based on the information given**

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_program_id_date_of_birth_process_date
ON dbo.TableB (program_id,date_of_birth,process_date);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TableA
ON dbo.TableA(program_id);
```

**Running the query**

```
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;
select 
a.*,b.date_of_birth
from dbo.TableA a 
left join ( select program_id,date_of_birth,max(process_date)  as maxprocess_date
            from dbo.TableB 
            group by program_id,date_of_birth) b
    on a.program_id=b.program_id;
```

[image]

The NC index on `TableA` is used since `ID` is included in the NC index and no other columns are in `TableA` except the `program_id` coluln, which is a key column of that index.

---

**But**, since you are using `select a.*` you will probably have to add all these columns to the 
NC index on `TableA` as included columns, which will increase your index size depending on the amount of columns in the table.

If we add a `varchar(3)` column and populate it with a value:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableA ADD bla varchar(3) 
DEFAULT ('bla')
WITH VALUES;
```

The index is no longer used:

[image]

Because of the additional `bla` column added:

[image]

**To fix this**, recreate the index with the `bla` column included.

```
DROP  INDEX IX_TableA ON dbo.TableA;
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TableA
ON dbo.TableA(program_id)
INCLUDE(bla);
```

---

**Additionally**

> None of these tables are indexed.

Heap tables are not ideal, you should consider adding a clustered index that makes sense and reading up on indexing.

More on the difference between heap tables and tables with a Clustered index [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1254/sql-server-clustered-tables-vs-heap-tables/)

> select  a.*

Using   `Select *` is not a good practice, consider naming all columns used in your select statement separately.

[Bad habits to kick : using SELECT *](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

---

**DDL + DML used for testing**

```
CREATE TABLE 
dbo.TableA(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
           program_id INT);
CREATE TABLE 
dbo.TableB(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
           program_id INT,
           date_of_birth date,
           process_date datetime2)
-- Dataset reduced by / 10 ~= 3 588 378

INSERT INTO 
dbo.TableA WITH(TABLOCK)  (program_id)
SELECT TOP(3588378) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) / 1000
FROM master..spt_values spt1
CROSS APPLY master..spt_values spt2;
-- values from 0 to 3588

-- Dataset reduced by / 10 ~= 2 734 333
INSERT INTO 
dbo.TableB WITH(TABLOCK) (program_id,date_of_birth,process_date) 
SELECT TOP(2734333) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) / 1000,
CAST('01/01/1990' AS date),
DATEADD(MINUTE,-ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),GETDATE()) -- one minute less to get distinct process_dates
FROM master..spt_values spt1
CROSS APPLY master..spt_values spt2;
-- values from 0 to 2734
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for detail and such a great explanation. yeah. It's picking up Hash match even after creating an indexes on join columns. I agree with you that other columns should also need to be included.

Comment: I have 57 cols for TableB but I am only selecting date_of_birth from tableB. so I guess it should be fine to have NC index on TableB for cols(program_id,date_of_birth,process_date).right?  Whereas TableA is having a list of 135 columns and I have made NC on just join column program_id.  So, do I need to include all the columns for TableA to make join more efficient?

Comment: @vikrantrana TableB should be fine. As of TableA, that is going to hurt depending on the size of these columns. Do you need to select them all as a result? Update / Delete / Insert behaviour gets slower depending on the amount of indexes and how big they are. It also obviously uses disk space. It is hard for others to determine the pro's / con's on that.

Comment: yes. I have to select all the columns from TableA

Comment: I have placed the actual query to provide more insights. Thanks for your support and time once again.

Comment: can we perform some more tuning on above query or it would be feasible to have all the columns as NC for TableA.?